# Combinatorics, find the number of integer solutions to an inequality

Tags: combinatorics

I have been given the following problem:

Find the number of *positive integer* solutions to
$$
a+b+c+d<50
$$

With no additional constraints given on how big or small $a,b,c$ or $d$ may be.

I have already introduced a new variable, $t$, to turn the inequality into an equation:
$$
a+b+c+d+t=50
$$

I am unsure as to what to do next. I assume I need to use the formula $C(50+5-1, 50)$, which is $$\begin{pmatrix}54\\50\end{pmatrix}$$
Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: You are only interested in positive solutions to that equality, so it's just $\binom {50-1}{5-1}$.  Your formula would count non-negative solutions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)